# Submit vote and lock using Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have the following to display a list of images (using Angular):

```
  var application = angular.module('Application', []);

  application.controller('ImageController', function ImageController($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('api/images').
      success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.images = data;
      }).
      error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      });

  });

</script>

<div data-ng-app="Application" data-ng-controller="ImageController" class="gallery">
  <div data-ng-repeat='image in images' class="image">
    <img src="{{image.Url}}" alt="" />
    <div class="overlay">
      <a href="#">VOTE</a>
      <span>{{image.Votes}}</span>
      <a href="#">LOCK</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The images are being displayed as expected but I would like to:

1. Call "api/vote/{{image.id}}" when the link VOTE is clicked;
2. Call "api/lock/{{image.id}}" when the link LOCK is clicked;

I suppose both links should be inside a form? No?

How can I do this? Could someone help me out?

**UPDATE**

I tried the following, as suggested by Dieter:

```
    <div class="overlay">
      <a ng-click="vote(image)" href="#">VOTE</a>
      <span>{{image.Votes}}</span>
    </div>

    $scope.vote = function (image) {

      $http.post('api/images/' + image.Id + '/vote', { id: image.Id }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          alert("success");
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          alert(data);
          alert(status);
        });

    };
```

With this I get a bad request ... If I try:

```
    $http.post('api/images/2/vote', { id: image.Id }).
```

Then it works ...

I checked and image.Id is equal to 2. Any idea why it does not work?

I am not sure how to create the path with parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ng-click to your links

```
<div class="overlay">
      <a ng-click="vote(image)" href="#">VOTE</a>
      <span>{{image.Votes}}</span>
      <a ng-click="lock(image)" href="#">LOCK</a>
    </div>
```

Then in your controller you can add the desired API calls inside the click functions

```
application.controller('ImageController', function ImageController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.vote = function (image) {
        // image.id is available here
    };

    $scope.lock = function (image) {
        // image.id is available here
    };

    $http.get('api/images').
      success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.images = data;
      }).
      error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      });

  });
```

Also try to avoid http` calls inside your controller. Make an abstraction by using an Angular service. And check out John Papa's [styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide), can't recommend this enough!

Comment: Having services will be the next step ... I am just starting with angular so first I needed to have this work.

Comment: I am still having a problem when using image.Id to call the action. any idea why? I just added an update with your code ...

Comment: Are you sure image.Id is available on your object (do `console.log(image)` before the `$http` call)? You can also check n chrome the network tab to see the url that's being posted to the service.

Comment: I found the problem. I API was expecting an Int as Id and I was passing a String.